# Automating webforms?

Tags: 7, webforms

I am making a website for a museum that involves a questionnaire. I made this questionnaire with the webforms module, which in turn sends the answers to another page to be processed. The people at the museum do not know drupal, let alone php. So when they want to add questions to the questionnaire, it has to be done by me. This is because I also need to change the values that are passed on the next page (via the redirect URL in the webforms module).

To automate the process for them (they probably know enough to be able to add new questions), I wanted to know if there is any way to pass on all the answers from the webforms questions, so that they do not have to fiddle with the php? This way, all answers will be sent, regardless of the questions on the webforms. The page that receives the values has been coded so that it takes any amount of URL-parameters; You do not have to find a way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module and the [Webform Rules](http://drupal.org/project/webform_rules) integration module to redirect to a generated URL.

You could create a rule that loops over the results building a custom URL string pointing to your processor script, and then redirect to that URL.

As long as the string is less than about [2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url) characters you should be in good shape.

You may want to look into the Form API as this would be much cleaner and possibly simpler with a custom submit handler.

- [Form API Quick Start Guide](http://drupal.org/node/751826)
- [Form API Reference Sheet](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7)

If I misunderstood your question I would be happy to try again if you'll clarify.