# submit all webform answers

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm creating a drupal website that will be maintained by others. To make it as simple as possible for them, I would like to automate as much as possible. Part of this is allowing them to add new webform questions without having to change the redirect URL (the answers will be processed in another node).

What I would like to do is catch ALL answers, regardless of the questions. So, it should work when there is one question or when there are 15 questions, without having to manually change the redirect parameters. Currently, I construct the URL manually by adding tokens for each question to the redirect URL.

I would prefer to use tokens in the webform's redirect URL. But I'm willing to write some code if it's the only way.

EDIT, extra info:

The node receiving the parameters has already been programmed to dynamically accept all arguments

Comment: Please, show how Redirect URL should look like and how it looks now for fixed questions count.

Comment: @kalabro It doesn't matter how the new URL will look like, I can adapt my processing code. The old URL has been lost when changing to the new alpha version (7.x-4.0-alpha4) of webforms, because it uses tokens in an entirely different manner. I am still trying to reconstruct the old URL, but I have yet to figure out how the new system works exactly.

Comment: It looks like you have already [got the answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38109/automating-webforms).

Comment: @kalabro Sort of. Was hoping for some more input though, by rephrasing and making it clearer. Because the webform rules module doesn't have any documentation - at least not that I can find.